# Convert contents of a list into dataframe

Tags: python

I have a list of strings named as 'master_list' having contents of the following pattern.

```
master_list = ['Ab', '$', 'str_1', 'str_2', '(1 month)', 'str_3', 'July(2 years)', 'str_4', 
    '(2 months)', 'str_5', 'Ab', 'str_6', 'str_7', 'Bat', '$', 'str_8', '(6 months)', 'str_9', 
    'str_10', 'str_11', 'May(11 months)', 'str_12', 'str_13', 'str_14', 'Bat', 'str_15', 'Cat', '$', 
    'str_16', 'str_17', 'str_18', '(2 weeks)', 'str_19', '(3 years)', 'str_20', '(1 year)', 'str_21', 
    'str_22', '(6 years)', 'str_23', 'Cat', 'str_24', 'str_25', 'str_26', 'Apple', '$', 'str_27 ', 
    'Oct(2 years)',  'str_28', 'str_29', 'Apple', 'str_30', 'str_31', 'str_32', 'Bc', '$', 
    'str_33', 'str_34', 'str_35', 'Jan(3 years)', 'str_36', '(11 years)', 'str_37', '(10 months)', 
    'str_38', 'str_39', 'Feb(2 years)', 'str_40', 'str_41', 'str_42', 'Bc']
```

I have another list named 'list_start' which have the following items.

```
list_start = ['Ab', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Apple', 'Bc']
```

I am trying to match the contents of list_start with the master_list and extract the following dataframe.

| Start | Strings | Time_Stamps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ab | str_2 | (1 month) |
| Ab | str_3 | July(2 years) |
| Ab | str_4 | (2 months) |
| Bat | str_8 | (6 months) |
| Bat | str_11 | May(11 months) |
| Cat | str_18 | (2 weeks) |
| Cat | str_19 | (3 years) |
| Cat | str_20 | (1 year) |
| Cat | str_22 | (6 years) |
| Apple | str_27 | Oct(2 years) |
| Bc | str_35 | Jan(3 years) |
| Bc | str_36 | (11 years) |
| Bc | str_37 | (10 months) |
| Bc | str_39 | Feb(2 years) |

There are some definite patterns which can be seen in the master_list.

Pattern-1 : Each item in the 'list_start' appears twice in the 'master_list'.

Pattern-2 : After every item of the 'list_start' in the 'master_list' there is a '$' sign.

Pattern-3 : Only those strings are extracted that appears just before the Time_Stamps.

Note : I have replaced the original string contents in the 'master_list' with 'str_1', 'str_2',...and so on, as it is easier to convey the message this way.

I am new to coding and this seems like an uphill task. It seems that a combination of for loop and while loop would solve the issue, but I am not able to wrap my head around this.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It *is* possible to do this, but my Spidey sense strongly suggests this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you could share more context, there's a good chance there might be a better approach in the first place.

Comment: @CrazyChucky..can you let me know what type of context you are looking for.  As for the problem above, I am asked to convert the list of strings into a dataframe of the format I mentioned above. And thank you for suggesting the XY problem approach, that really helps with the critical thinking for moving forward with any problem. Cheers mate!!

Comment: If this is an assignment, and you simply have to do it with this input, then do what you gotta do. If you ever find yourself in a situation where you're writing a larger program and one part of your program has produced a list this unwieldy, it suggests that you should probably rethink the part that produces it, rather than figure out a way to process it.

Answer (score 1):

Not much pythonic here, hey it works.

Code:

```
master_list = ['Ab', '$', 'str_1', 'str_2', '(1 month)', 'str_3', 'July(2 years)', 'str_4', 
    '(2 months)', 'str_5', 'Ab', 'str_6', 'str_7', 'Bat', '$', 'str_8', '(6 months)', 'str_9', 
    'str_10', 'str_11', 'May(11 months)', 'str_12', 'str_13', 'str_14', 'Bat', 'str_15', 'Cat', '$', 
    'str_16', 'str_17', 'str_18', '(2 weeks)', 'str_19', '(3 years)', 'str_20', '(1 year)', 'str_21', 
    'str_22', '(6 years)', 'str_23', 'Cat', 'str_24', 'str_25', 'str_26', 'Apple', '$', 'str_27 ', 
    'Oct(2 years)',  'str_28', 'str_29', 'Apple', 'str_30', 'str_31', 'str_32', 'Bc', '$', 
    'str_33', 'str_34', 'str_35', 'Jan(3 years)', 'str_36', '(11 years)', 'str_37', '(10 months)', 
    'str_38', 'str_39', 'Feb(2 years)', 'str_40', 'str_41', 'str_42', 'Bc']
    
list_start = ['Ab', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Apple', 'Bc']

data = []  
Start, Strings, Time_Stamps, prv_s = ('', '', '', '') 
 
for s in  master_list:
    if s in list_start:
        Start = s
    elif s == '$':
        continue
    elif 'week' in s or 'month' in s or 'year' in s:
        Time_Stamps = s
        data.append([Start, Strings, Time_Stamps])
    else:
        Strings = s
    prv_s = s
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
['Ab', 'str_2', '(1 month)']
['Ab', 'str_3', 'July(2 years)']
['Ab', 'str_4', '(2 months)']
['Bat', 'str_8', '(6 months)']
['Bat', 'str_11', 'May(11 months)']
['Cat', 'str_18', '(2 weeks)']
['Cat', 'str_19', '(3 years)']
['Cat', 'str_20', '(1 year)']
['Cat', 'str_22', '(6 years)']
['Apple', 'str_27 ', 'Oct(2 years)']
['Bc', 'str_35', 'Jan(3 years)']
['Bc', 'str_36', '(11 years)']
['Bc', 'str_37', '(10 months)']
['Bc', 'str_39', 'Feb(2 years)']
```

Comment: ...thanks for the reply. The above code works perfect. But I do have a query. What if the other strings (str_1, str_2,..) contain the word years, weeks or months but not within brackets. How do I distinguish between the two time_stamps, one within the bracket (the ones we need) and the other time_stamps in the strings(str_1, str_2,..)

Comment: elif 'weeks)' in s or 'months)' in s or 'years)' in s or 'week)' in s or 'month)' in s or 'year)' in s:    ---- we can write a custom function str_contains to check all of this to make it more readable